# Video.js: Error after setting video src

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

I'm having trouble using video.js when running `videojs('vid')`. My goal is to create a video.js object so I can read the current time (`myPlayer.currentTime`).

HTML:

```
<video id="vid" class="video-js" controls autoplay data-setup="{}">
    <source id="src1">
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    videojs('vid').ready(function () {
        var myPlayer = this;
        myPlayer.src({ type: 'video/mp4', src: '/uploads/365.mp4' });
    });
});
```

This gives me an error:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

**important**: When Setting the src without performing `videojs('vid')`, the same video works fine. It's like running `videojs('vid')` resets all sources and fails to set the `src` via Javascript.

Comment: Any reason why you can't get the currentTime from the `<video>` element?

Comment: Thats not possible.

Comment: Why? If you really want this you can put a dummy url in the source, and then change it the way you like. `<source id="src1" src=".mp4">`. But I still think `<video>.currentTime` is the best approach.

Comment: Read about video.js currenttime is not valid. You need to create an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I self-solved the problem by changing the `src: '/uploads/365.mp4'` to a full URL path: `https://example.com/uploads/365.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `currentTime` in videojs with it's `currentTime()` function.

```js
var output = document.querySelector('output');
var player = videojs('vid');

requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);

function updateTime() {
  output.innerText = player.currentTime();
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.0.1/alt/video-js-cdn.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.0.1/video.min.js"></script>

<video id="vid" class="video-js" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>

<output></output>
```